# In my wordpress site I want to start somefile.html first and after 10 seconds redirect to index.php file

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site http://hamroletang.com and it contain a file http://hamroletang.com/sardanjali.html

Now I want sardanjali.html to be my website landing page.

Then it will redirect to index.php which i have done already

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to rename sardanjali.html to index.html and add:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://hamroletang.com/index.php'">
```

Then, make sure that in your Apache config .html takes precedence over .php

Comment: Thanks but I tried this and what it will do is, it will keep on redirecting to index.html file instead of going to index.php

Answer (score 0):

You can rename sardanjali.html to index.html and then change in the apache config the directory index to have index.html before index.php:

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

On my system this was already the default (ubuntu).

In your redirect you should explicitly redirect to index.php, and not to the domain in general.

If you cannot change apache config files and renaming to index.html doesn't help, then you can move your blog to a subdomain or subdirectory and redirect into that. But that would break all the links to your blog. Probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks but I tried this and what it will do is, it will keep on redirecting to index.html file instead of going to index.php

Comment: You should redirect to http://hamroletang.com/index.php and not to http://hamroletang.com

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default page of your website to whatever you want it to be. In your case specify the single file sardanjali.html as your default page. The settings vary between web servers. e.g. on Apache here are the instructions - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-display-or-change-a-default-page-other-than-indexhtml/

And yes, you have to use the refresh in your sardanjali.html to automatically redirect the user to your index.php after the specified time.